# Monthly loop with missing rows

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to do a loop that displays the count of entries next to the month link, but since the count just skips a row when there are no entries in the query, the count for the links does not work. How would I work this out since I cannot do a simple array loop due to missing rows. Here is what I've been trying:

QUERY RESULTS

```
count   month
1   1
63  3
21  4
7   5
3   6
6   7
```

PHP

```
// NEW MONTH COUNT
public function new_month_count() {

    $year = $this->chosen_year();
    $main_sql = $this->month_count_sql() . " AND YEAR(exp_date) = " . $year . " GROUP BY MONTH(exp_date) ORDER BY MONTH(exp_date), month";
    $res = $this->conn->query($main_sql);



    $array = array();
    $array[0] = 0;
    $i = 1;
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        $array[$i] = ($row['month'] == $i ? $row['count'] : 0);
        $i += 1;
    }

    return $array;  

}


// CREATE MONTHLY LINKS
public function monthly_links() {

    $count = $this->new_month_count();

    $months = array('','January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August', 'September','October','November','December');
    for ($i=1 ; $i <= 12 ; $i++) {
        $array[] = "<a href='monthly.php?month=" . $i . "&status=3'>" . $months[$i] . " " . $this->chosen_year() . "&emsp; ( " . $count[$i] . " )</a>";
    }
    return $array;

}
```

The output works if there is no skipped month in the query result, but if the row is skipped, only the 6th month will show a count of 6... Strange.

Comment: Which RDMBS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would treat the array like a Dictionary and check if the result contained a value for the month:

```
// NEW MONTH COUNT
```

public function new_month_count() {

```
$year = $this->chosen_year();
$main_sql = $this->month_count_sql() . " AND YEAR(exp_date) = " . $year . " GROUP BY MONTH(exp_date) ORDER BY MONTH(exp_date), month";
$res = $this->conn->query($main_sql);

$array = array();

while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[$row['month']] = $row['count'];
}

return $array;
```

}

// CREATE MONTHLY LINKS
public function monthly_links() {

```
$count = $this->new_month_count();

$months = array('','January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August', 'September','October','November','December');
for ($i=1 ; $i <= 12 ; $i++) {

    $tempCount = 0;

    if(isset($count[$i]) ) {
        $tempCount = $count[$i]
    }

    $array[] = "<a href='monthly.php?month=" . $i . "&status=3'>" . $months[$i] . " " . $this->chosen_year() . "&emsp; ( " . $tempCount . " )</a>";
}
return $array;
```

}

note: this isn't tested, but hope this helps